# Remove people´s second names from CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv, split

I want to remove the second name from the list, so that i can process them further later.

The code  creates a file with the changed name, but it stays the same. i dont know that much about python so id appreciate if someone explains what we did wrong

```
import csv
import os

def remove_second_names(full_name):
    name_parts = full_name.split()
    first_name = name_parts[0]
    first_name = first_name[0].upper() + first_name[1:].lower()
    return first_name

csv_file_path = input("Geben Sie den Pfad zur CSV-Datei ein: ")

try:
    with open(csv_file_path, 'r', newline='') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')
        rows = [row for row in reader]

    for i, row in enumerate(rows):
        if len(row) >= 2:
            row[1] = remove_second_names(row[1])
            rows[i] = row

    base_file_name = os.path.basename(csv_file_path)
    output_file_path = base_file_name.replace('.csv', '_bearbeitet.csv')

    with open(output_file_path, 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter='\t')
        writer.writerows(rows)

    print("Die bearbeiteten Daten wurden in die Datei '{}' geschrieben.".format(output_file_path))

except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Die angegebene Datei wurde nicht gefunden.")
except Exception as e:
    print("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten:", str(e))
```

the csv file looks like that:

```
Name;Firstname Secondname;10EH2;
Name;Firstname-Secondname;10EH3;
Name;Firstname Secondname OtherName;10EH3;
```

i want it to look like this after running the code (obviously the will be real names instead of the placeholders):

```
Name;Firstname;10EH2;
Name;Firstname;10EH3;
Name;Firstname;10EH3;
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You have `delimiter='\t'` but your file seems to use semicolons, not tabs, as delimiters.

Comment: Also, this looks like homework / practice, but it's worth reading https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ anyway

Comment: `name_parts = full_name.split()` splits on spaces. It won't work for the second row in your example

Comment: Just to be clear, the essence of your question is how to get the first name, not for example how to rewrite the csv with semicolon delimiters right?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the `re` package as it will allow you to split on "non-word" characters like `" "` and `"-"` fairly easily.

```py
import re

def remove_second_names(full_name):
    return re.split(r"\W", full_name)[0]

print(remove_second_names("Firstname"))
print(remove_second_names("Firstname Secondname"))
print(remove_second_names("Firstname-Secondname"))
```

That should give you:

```
Firstname
Firstname
Firstname
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it's considered bad practice to change the list (or any iterable) while you're iterating over it. It's usually better to e.g. prepare a "result" iterable, into which you will add your desired results.

Then a few points that should assist you:

- You have a semicolon delimited file, yet you specify the delimiter to be a tab character in `csv.reader` and `csv.writer`
- You use `str.split()` which only splits by white spaces, but your sample also shows a potential use of a hyphen as a separator, and that case isn't addressed

Comment: Changing elements of the list is fine. You shouldn't _remove_ elements from the list as you iterate over it.

Comment: While changing elements is indeed fine (as in, it won't crash the code), it is still considered bad practice as it makes the code less readable. For beginner developers, it also easily leads to adding and removing items while iterating.